# How to connect Arduino to AC motor

Tags: arduino, ac-motor

I want to connect from Arduino Uno to AC 1.5 kW single phase motor for my cement mixer project. I was want to try to create a switch on off by using code in Arduino and  I was thinking to add several components such as relay and contactor between Arduino and AC motor but I was thinking does it work or I just need to add another component?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You will need:

- A contactor with contacts rated for motor starting of your motor.
- Suitable fuse / circuit breaker or motor overload module. (Do not think, "I can just test without these".)
- A relay module designed to be switched by a 5 V logic-level signal.
- A suitable box to protect the components and the user.
- An isolator switch so that the motor can be stopped if the Arduino or the software fails.